# Manage two databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, configuration, config

I have a config file (.php) in my project, which contains an array with the settings for the all project. This array has a structure similar to this:

```
'db' =>
    'prod' =>
        'host'     => ''
        'dbname'   => ''
        'username' => ''
        'password' => ''
    'local' =>
        'host'     => ''
        'dbname'   => ''
        'username' => ''
        'password' => ''
'other' => 'settings'
```

My question is: how will I manage those double connection information ?

Should I, later in this file, if I am in local, put the local information in the prod array ? Or should I use multiple files for configuration, and include the good one in this config.php (which I would then include in every file of this project) ?

How would you do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: detect local\prod use some code to decide witch credentials to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dagon says, usually you detect in which enviroment you are and read one configuration or another.

You can detect it through PHP. You can read the Hostname from PHP and define the constant accordingly:

```
if(!defined('APPLICATION_ENV')) {
   if(FALSE === stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']), 'www.example.com') {
       define(APPLICATION_ENV, 'development');
   } else {
       define(APPLICATION_ENV, 'production');
   }
}
```

This way, you don't have to rely on the environment setting at all.

Once this has been set (either in your Apache's configuration, or at the system level), you can read its value using the getenv function :

```
echo getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```

If you want to know more about this you can read this post:
[Set Application_ENV via virtual host config and read this in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378871/set-application-env-via-virtual-host-config-and-read-this-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

By using the comment of @Dagon and the answer of @Pere Pages, I arrived to a solution which suits me:

In my `$config` array, I have 3 arrays: `use`, `prod` and `local`.

In `use` I can put settings which won't change depending on the environment (production or localhost) and I also have the settings which change depending on the environment, but they are empty.

In `prod` and `local`, I have the settings adapted for each environment (the ones which are empty in `use`).

In the same file, I go over each line of `use` (foreach), and for the empty ones, I fill them with the appropriate value coming from `prod` or `local`, depending on my `APPLICATION_ENV` (is set to `local` on my machine).

Thank you.