# Nginx: How to set environment variable in server block

Tags: nginx, environment-variables

Simply, I want to achieve same thing of apache vhosts: [Set Application_ENV via virtual host config and read this in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378871/set-application-env-via-virtual-host-config-and-read-this-in-php) for nginx. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is use `fastcgi_param` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099167/134824) and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/351702/85322).

I prefered another method. Since I'm using GIT as my VCS:

1. I created a file in the root of my project named it "env.conf",
   which contains only 1 string ("production", "development", etc) which is the environment name
2. Ignored this file in **.gitignore**.
3. Read the file and check the value as the first thing in my application starting point.